# Countdown timer in panel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, time, conky

Is there some widget that I can put in the panel of my Xubuntu system that will show me a countdown of time? I've tried `pystopwatch`, but although it minimizes, it doesn't show me how long I have left. I've also tried xfce `timer-plugin`, but it doesn't really minimize. I just need something that will show how much time left I have for a certain task, as inconspicuously as possible. I'm running Xubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer will be not on panel. Im using conky to make it visible on desktop

**Step 1.**

Install conky

```
sudo apt-get install conky
```

**Step 2.**

Pearl Package

You may need to install libdate-manip-perl and libtime-modules-perl packages.

```
sudo apt-get install  libdate-manip-perl libtime-modules-perl
```

**Step 3.**

Save at home folder

- **[.conkycount](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1260481/)**
- **[.countdown](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1260435/)**

Locate **${alignc}Countdown** in .conkycount to change **Countdown** text.

Locate **"October 26, 2012"** in .countdown to change date.

**Step 4.**

Give permission to script

```
chmod +x ~/.countdown
```

**Step 5.**

Run your conky

By terminal:

```
conky -c ~/.conkycount
```

Make startup application

Open startup application

> ```
> Name : ConkyCount
>
> Command : conky -p 20 -c ~/.conkycount
> ```

Result

[image]

Comment: That's really nice. Thanks. I do need it for the panel though. I'm recording a screencast that takes the whole screen save the panel, that's why I needed this. Impressive work, though.

Comment: Thanks! This conky will visible on top of all application, just tweak the alignment, size so the conky will not disturb your workspace. ;)

Comment: Btw, cant you just right click you pystopwatch and click at visible on top?

Comment: Darn, that's a great idea. Accepted... sooo simple! :)

Comment: Yeah.. Enjoy Xubuntu!

Comment: @penreturns, the paste.ubuntu.com links are now dead :(

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the countdown time to a tmp file and use conky to display its contents. Here's a script based on @penreturns' answer that does this for as long as the timer is running. IOW the config won't load when the timer is idle. Anyhow, there are two steps you need to follow. First, you need to add the timer script to your bin directory and make it executable (see @penreturns' answer):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
conky -q -c ~/.conky/.conkyrc-timer &

pid=$(pgrep -f conkyrc-timer)
TMPFILE=$(mktemp -t countdown.XXXXXXXX)
date=$(($(date +%s) + $1 * 60))

function cleanup {
    rm -f "$TMPFILE"
    [ "$pid" ] && kill "$pid"
    clear
    exit 1
}
trap 'cleanup' INT EXIT

while [ "$date" -ge "$(date +%s)" ]; do
    time=$(date -u --date @$(("$date" - $(date +%s))) +%M:%S)
    echo -ne "$time\r"
    echo -ne "$time" > "$TMPFILE"

    if [[ $(cat "$TMPFILE") == "00:00" ]]; then
    echo -ne "Time expired" > "$TMPFILE"
    fi
    sleep 0.1
done
```

Then you need to create a config file (for example: `~/.conky/.conkyrc-timer`) with:

```lua
conky.config = {
   alignment = 'bottom_right',
   double_buffer = true,
   use_xft = true,
   gap_x = 0,
   gap_y = 0,
   own_window = true,
   own_window_type = 'dock',
   update_interval = 0.1,
}

conky.text = [[
$alignr${exec cat /tmp/countdown*}\
]]
```

And that's all. Now when you run `timer N` from the terminal you should see the elapsed time on the lower right corner of your screen.